# Where can I get other Authentication options for IIS?

Tags: authentication

I notice that other IIS Admin have the following Authentication options:

[image]

But I only have the first two Authentication options - `Anonymous Authentication` and `ASP.NET Impersonation`.

How can I get the rest of the options display in the Authentication of my IIS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to the Add Role Services and select the type of authentication options under the `Security` section as shown below.

[image]